# Spooling status on a Print Job for a Network Printer served by Print Server

Tags: printing, server, spooler

I'm trying to understand how Network Printing works and the meaning of Print Job statuses.

When you have a Network Printer being served up by a Print Server (Win 2008 R2 x64), is the following true on how a Print Job is handled from a PC (Win7 x64)?

**Installation Process:**

1. User installs Printer from Print Server
2. PC downloads the printer drivers from the Print Server and installs local versions on the PC.

**Print Job Submission**

1. User Submits Print Job from 32-bit MS Word to a Network Printer
2. PC checks Print Server to verify local printer drivers are current according to those available from Print Server.  Updates drivers if necessary.
3. PC utilizes drivers to package the print job.
4. Print job is sent to the Client Print Spooler (splWOW64.exe) and job is sent to Print Server
5. Print Server's Print Spooler (spoolsv.exe) receives the job and manages the Printer's queue.
6. Print Job is submitted to Printer

If I open the Print Queue from the Print Server and I see "Spooling" on a user's print job.  Where in the process is the print job stuck?  Between the PC and the Server, or the Server and the Printer?

I've checked the PC's C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS and it is empty.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [sf] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Apologies, thank you.